# Is there a way to pass a flag to the service call inorder to filter out in angular interceptor file(other than passing it as a param in request)?

Tags: javascript, angular, https, angular-cli, angular-http-interceptors

I need to pass a flag to the service request call in order to filter out and do some actions for the request in the angular interceptor file.

Is there any **angular specific methods** available to implement this functionality, other than modifying the request with flag as query-param or body param.

FYI: -Angular version 8

Comment: You could also use a custom header but it is still rather a workaround but there is no such specific functionality for this use case.

Comment: From when I tried to do something similar, the only option was to add a custom header that the interceptors could check and then remove.

Comment: From my research I got to know that, there is a new feature available in Angular v12 where we can pass user defined values to the request using context. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpContext

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service to hold the updated flag,and inject that service to the interceptor and then do whatever you need to do with the request nor the data that is being sent